# XML - System.Xml.XmlException - hexadecimal value 0x06

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I get this error. Later I searched and found out the reason of illegal characters in my XML and its solution. But I don't have the access to edit any of these files. My job is to read and fetch the tag value, attribute value and similar stuff. SO I can't replace the binary characters with escapes like '\x01' with &#01. Also I tried to include CheckCharacters =false in XMLreader settings. It doesn't take this. Still it is throwing the same error.

Is it not possible to fix in XMLreader? I read about XMLtextReader. It can skip the exception. But already I have coded for all my features using XMLreader. It would be good if I can find a solution for this. Otherwise I would have to change all my code.

My code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            var filenames = System.IO.Directory
                        .EnumerateFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.xml", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Select(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath);



            foreach (var f in filenames)
            {
                var resolver = new XmlUrlOverrideResolver();
                resolver.DtdFileMap[@"X1.DTD"] = @"\\location\X1.DTD";
                resolver.DtdFileMap[@"R2.DTD"] = @"\\location\X2.DTD";
                resolver.DtdFileMap[@"R5.DTD"] = @"\\location\R5.DTD";
                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

                settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
                settings.XmlResolver = resolver;
                XmlReader doc = XmlReader.Create(f, settings);
                while (doc.Read())
                {
                    if ((doc.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (doc.Name == "ap"))
                {
                    if (doc.HasAttributes)
                    {

                        String fin = doc.GetAttribute("ap");
                        if (fin == "no")
                        {


                            String[] array = new String[10000];
                            array[i] = (f);

                            File.AppendAllText(@"\\location\NAPP.txt", array[i] + Environment.NewLine);
                            i++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String[] abs = new String[10000];
                            abs[i] = (f);
                            File.AppendAllText(@"\\location\APP.txt", abs[i] + Environment.NewLine);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple example of character "filter" that will replae the 0x06 character with a space:

```
public class MyStreamReader : StreamReader {
    public MyStreamReader(string path)
        : base(path) {
    }

    public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count) {            
        int res = base.Read(buffer, index, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < res; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == 0x06) {
                buffer[i] = ' ';
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

You use it this way:

```
using (var sr = new MyStreamReader(f)) {
    var doc = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings);
```

Note that it's very simple because it's replacing a character (the 0x06) with another character of the same "length" (the space). If you wanted to replace a character with a "sequence" of characters (to escape it), it would get more complex (not impossible, 30 minutes of work difficult)

(I have checked and it seems the `XmlTextReader` only uses that method and not the `Read()` method)

As always, when a programmer tells you 30 minutes, it means 0 minutes or 2 hours :-)

This is the "more complex" `ReplacingStreamReader`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Only the Read methods are supported!
/// </summary>
public class ReplacingStreamReader : StreamReader
{
    public ReplacingStreamReader(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
    }

    public Func<char, string> ReplaceWith { get; set; }

    protected char[] RemainingChars { get; set; }
    protected int RemainingCharsIndex { get; set; }


    public override int Read()
    {
        int ch;

        if (RemainingChars != null)
        {
            ch = RemainingChars[RemainingCharsIndex];
            RemainingCharsIndex++;

            if (RemainingCharsIndex == RemainingChars.Length)
            {
                RemainingCharsIndex = 0;
                RemainingChars = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ch = base.Read();

            if (ch != -1)
            {
                string replace = ReplaceWith((char)ch);

                if (replace == null)
                {
                    // Do nothing
                }
                else if (replace.Length == 1)
                {
                    ch = replace[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    ch = replace[0];

                    RemainingChars = replace.ToCharArray(1, replace.Length - 1);
                    RemainingCharsIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        return ch;
    }

    public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        int res = 0;

        // We leave error handling to the StreamReader :-)
        // We handle only "working" parameters
        if (RemainingChars != null && buffer != null && index >= 0 && count > 0 && index + count <= buffer.Length)
        {
            int remainingCharsCount = RemainingChars.Length - RemainingCharsIndex;
            res = Math.Min(remainingCharsCount, count);

            Array.Copy(RemainingChars, RemainingCharsIndex, buffer, index, res);

            RemainingCharsIndex += res;

            if (RemainingCharsIndex == RemainingChars.Length)
            {
                RemainingCharsIndex = 0;
                RemainingChars = null;
            }

            if (res == count)
            {
                return res;
            }

            index += res;
            count -= res;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            List<char> sb = null;

            int res2 = base.Read(buffer, index, count);

            if (res2 == 0 || ReplaceWith == null)
            {
                return res;
            }

            int j = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < res2; i++)
            {
                char ch = buffer[index + i];
                string replace = ReplaceWith(ch);

                if (sb != null)
                {
                    if (replace == null)
                    {
                        sb.Add(ch);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.AddRange(replace);
                    }
                }
                else if (replace == null)
                {
                    buffer[j] = ch;
                    j++;
                }
                else if (replace.Length == 1)
                {
                    buffer[j] = replace[0];
                    j++;
                }
                else if (replace.Length == 0)
                {
                    // We do not advance
                }
                else
                {
                    sb = new List<char>();
                    sb.AddRange(replace);
                }
            }

            res2 = j;

            if (sb != null)
            {
                int res3 = Math.Min(sb.Count, count - res2);
                sb.CopyTo(0, buffer, index + res2, res3);

                if (res3 < sb.Count)
                {
                    RemainingChars = new char[sb.Count - res3];
                    RemainingCharsIndex = 0;
                    sb.CopyTo(res3, RemainingChars, 0, RemainingChars.Length);
                }

                res += res3;
            }
            else
            {
                res2 = j;

                // Can't happen if sb != null (at least a character must
                // have been added)
                if (res2 == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            res += res2;
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
using (var sr = new ReplacingStreamReader(f))
{
    sr.ReplaceWith = x =>
    {
        return x == 0x6 ? " " : null;
        // return x == '.' ? "&#160;" : null; // Replace all . with &nbsp;
    };

    var doc = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings);
```

Be aware that the `ReplacingStreamReader` doesn't "know" which part of the xml it is modifying, so rarely a "blind" replace is ok :-) Other than this limitation, you can replace any character with any string (`null` in the `ReplaceWith` means "keep the current character", equivalent to `x.ToString()` in the example given. Returning `string.Empty` is valid, means remove the current character).

The class is quite interesting: it keeps a `char[] RemainingChars` with the chars that have been read (and filtered by `ReplaceWith`) but that haven't been returned by a `Read()` method because the passed buffer was too much small (the `ReplaceWith` method could "enlarge" the read string, making it too much big for the `buffer`!). Note that `sb` is a `List<char>` instead of a `StringBuilder`. Probably using one or the other would be nearly equivalent, code-wise.

Comment: (a) shouldn't it be `0x01` and (b) I think the OP wants to replace the characters...

Comment: @CommuSoft The title says 0x06 :-) But that can be changed quickly, and this is a quick solution. As I've written, it gets more complex to do a full replacement.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It worked wonderfully. Sorry for the late acknowledgement. I was sick last 2 weeks and returned back to work today. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could first read the content into a `string` replace (escape) the content, and then load it into a `XmlReader`:

```
foreach (var f in filenames) {
    string text;
    using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(f,Encoding.UTF8)) {
        text = s.ReadToEnd();
    }
    text = text.Replace("\x01",@"&#01"); //replace the content

    //load some settings
    var resolver = new XmlUrlOverrideResolver();
    resolver.DtdFileMap[@"X1.DTD"] = @"\\location\X1.DTD";
    resolver.DtdFileMap[@"R2.DTD"] = @"\\location\X2.DTD";
    resolver.DtdFileMap[@"R5.DTD"] = @"\\location\R5.DTD";
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    settings.XmlResolver = resolver;
    XmlReader doc = XmlReader.Create(text, settings);

    //perform processing task
    //...
}
```